# Django annotation + filtering

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

I've some data that I've loaded from SQLite to PSQL using pgloader, it works more or less but some types are a bit clunky, so that's why my dates are in string, but I don't think that's the issue ( might be wrong here)

Consider the following models:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    hash_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
class Education(models.Model):
    hash_code = models.ForeignKey('Users', models.CASCADE)
    startdate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    enddate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
class Job(models.Model):
    hash_code = models.ForeignKey('Users', models.CASCADE)
    jobends = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobstarts = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm trying to get all the jobs after X years from the user's first Education.
So far I've got a Subquery, to get the first education's start date for each user:

```py
# This should return a date eg: '2000-01-01'
mba_start_subq = Educations.objects.filter(hash_code=OuterRef('hash_code'))
        .order_by('startdate')
        .values('startdate')[:1]
    )
```

Then I append this to each Job via:

```py
jobs = (Job.objects.all()
        # .distinct('hash_code')
        .order_by('hash_code')
        .annotate(mba_start = Subquery(mba_start_subq))
       )
```

So far so good, the issue is when I try to add a .filter() afterwards it takes ages to get the response (basically an infinite loop kind of thing)

```py
       # Filtering with date strings works
        jobs.filter(
            Q(jobstarts__lt = '2000-01-01'),
            Q(jobends__gt = '2002-01-01')
        )

       # this is the desired functionality, that doesn't work
        jobs.filter(
            Q(jobstarts__lt = Subquery(mba_start_subq)),
            Q(jobends__gt = Subquery(mba_start_subq))
        )
```

I've also tried to use F(annotated_value) in the .filter() after I've annotated it to the queryset, but no luck, I don't get any response from the server at all, takes ages.

What did I miss? the way I'm getting the education start date is wrong? Is there a more efficient way?

UPDATE: Here is a working SQL query that I would like to achieve in Django

```sql
 SELECT 
    Organizations.id, 
    Organizations.hash_code, 
    educations.EducationDegree,
    Organizations.Role,
    Organizations.Industry, 
    Organizations.JObStarts, 
    Educations.StartDate, 
    Organizations.JobEnds 
 FROM educations
 INNER JOIN Organizations ON 
 Organizations.hash_code=Educations.hash_code
 WHERE (date(Educations.StartDate,'+1 year') 
 BETWEEN Organizations.JObStarts AND Organizations.JobEnds ) 
 GROUP BY Organizations.hash_code
```

Comment: How large is your dataset, as in how many `Job`s and `User`s and such do you have? Perhaps it taking ages is just normal. This is probably unlikely though, but worth making sure.

Comment: i have a couple hundred thousands of jobs, i did think about it too so added extra filters, like industry  + role, where i expect < 1000 rows, without the jobstart filter its fine.  as soon as I want to filter by the annotated value, it's way too slow

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I have modified your Education and Job models slightly to use the Django User rather than the extra model you are adding. The new model definitions are:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    hash_code = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE)
    startdate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    enddate = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Job(models.Model):
    hash_code = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, models.CASCADE)
    jobends = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    jobstarts = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then, in order to match the SQL query you have, I would use the following:

```
subq = Education.objects.filter(hash_code__id=OuterRef('hash_code__id'))
                        .order_by('startdate')
```

This uses the ID of the User object rather than the entire object itself for filtering. The values can also be added as part of the sub-query after.
The final jobs query can then be run as follows:

```
jobs = Job.objects.filter(jobstarts__lt=Subquery(subq.values('startdate')[:1]),
                          jobends__gt=Subquery(subq.values('startdate'[:1]))
                  .order_by('hash_code__id')
```

This removes the need to order and annotate all Jobs objects and applies a simple, more efficient filter instead. I hope this helps. Let me know if it isn't quite what you are after.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work, I've tried to limit the results to let's say 10 jobs, but still runs forever.  I've managed to do another query that's more or less what I want, but 5000 jobs take ~ 10 minutes to query. Probably we will need to find another solution! Thanks anyways!